# Is it correct to add a question mark to the end of a sentence beginning with "Please"?

Tags: end-punctuation

I frequently use sentences such as:

> Please share information about X with me.

or

> Please let me know if I can help you further.

I tend to end sentences that I begin with a full stop. I don't recall where I learned to do this. One of my colleagues recently suggested that I use a question mark at the end of a sentence (typically a request) beginning with "Please" with a question mark to make it clearer that this is a request.

I can't seem to find a grammatical rule or guideline about this. Please would someone either help clarify this for me, or point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that a question mark was appropriate unless the request is in the form of a question - "Please can you do this?"

Comment: Okay, I'd use a question mark for the *would* not the *please*:  Please would someone either help clarify this for me?

Answer (score 2):

Requests can be formulated as questions, but the syntax has to be  that of a question or at least the intonation must correspond to that of a question (rising), and in this second case, in writing, a question  mark is used so as to show that the sentence is really a question in spite of the syntax, which corresponds to that of an assertion. The idea in  opting for a question is to avoid  the imperative, this  being  so because the  imperative mood is  used for giving orders, and  that   without  the addition of some  terms  such  as "please" or "would you?" it can sound harsh,  especially when talking  with people  that you do  not  know well. Except for elliptical questions without subject or  verb,  or  both, question marks are not used. Here is a note from CoGEL (*A  comprehensive grammar of the English language*) concerning marginal use of question marks.

> (**CoGEL**) **Note**
> Use of more than one question mark or exclamation mark or combinations of the two to suggest extreme doubt or surprise is confined to very informal writing such as stories for children.

Using a  question mark in a  form that is  basically an order is nonsense.